# Entity framework 6 cache query result?

Tags: c#, sql-server, caching, entity-framework-6

I have a problem during development test, but also in pre-production environment (and so, i suppose in production too).

Everytime I modify a data directly on database (from outside my application), it's like my application do not see any change and still retrieve old data. Of course, I do commit. 
My application use EF6.1.3. I thought EF had a cache o something like that. But I read:

> Entity Framework does not currently support caching of query results. A sample EF Caching provider is available for Entity Framework version 5 and earlier but due to changes to the provider model this sample provider does not work with Entity Framework 6 and newer.

So if it is not EF cache what can be and how can I solve?

I know in production environment I will not change data directly from db, but in future we are going to develope another application will use the same database and the same data.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because `Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` was set to `false` in your database context. This should be true by default, I think you should check in the constructor first before you do this in your context's constructor.

`Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;`